# How to pronounce references in the Bible?

Tags: bible, reference-request

If you see a reference to (2 Mc 7:1, 20-31) [tomorrow's Old Testament reading](http://www.usccb.org/bible/readings/112013.cfm)  how are you supposed to pronounce that?  And what if it spans two different chapters?

In Catechism class, sometimes I need to ask kids to look stuff up referenced like that and I don't know how to succinctly say it to them.  Other times they need to say the reference while reading something in the textbook and they always skip it because they don't know how to say it.

What I want is a pronunciation guide to go with the style guide for referencing bible passages that the publishers of the [Faith life Series](http://www.ignatius.com/promotions/FaithAndLIfe/) would expect me to teach the kids, so we can read their books.

Comment: I would say, "Second document of the Maccabees, Chapter one, Verses one and twenty-one to thirty-one."

Comment: I would just write it on the board, if you have one. This seems like a primarily opinion based question. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I'd go shorter than @Anonymous: Two Maccabees seven one and twenty to thirty-one. I might insert "Verses" if two adjacent numbers leads to ambiguity. And spanning two chapters: Isaiah 56 5 to 57 4. But this question demands answers which are purely opinion: as long as the reference is clear, there are many ways of reading it. Sorry.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It could be objectively answered if I asked it on [English.se] I just didn't want to ask it there because the experts are here.  (haven't met many other Catechists though)

Comment: Does it really matter?  You're telling them where to go if they want to follow along. Whatever best communicates that is what you should go with.

Comment: @AffableGeek I don't know if you teach kids from a text very often, but lots of times they read something and they almost always skip over whatever is in parentheses because they don't know how to say it.  I would like a little guide I can show them for "how to pronounce standard bible references".

Comment: So, do you mean just the names of the books or the names of the people in the books.  (And, yeah, I do - but I'll admit, I was usually telling them where to turn, and in doing so, I'd give them a pronounciation.

Comment: http://netministries.org/Bbasics/bwords.htm#  That might help though.... There are also books that go under the title of "Guide to Pronouncing Biblical Names."  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Not the names of the books, but how to say chapter 1, verse 3 through 35 chapter 2 verses 7 and 8 (when the reference looks more like a perl script)

Comment: If this question were asked by someone with 1 rep, I suspect nobody would have a problem answering it. Why are we giving Peter such a hard time?

Comment: @Flimzy I think I was too vague when I asked the question last night since everyone who commented thought I was asking something different.  I couldn't find any help on the internet or in my books, so that's why I asked. (and I'm teaching the class in a few hours so I guess I'll just make something up)  I think I'll go with your second suggestion as the most natural way of saying it.  But I'd like a big long answer (maybe an audioclip link), if possible.

Comment: A Lutheran minister once told me his system for pronouncing the complicated-looking names in the Bible: Pronounce them in some plausible way, and act as if you know what you're doing. Chances are, no one will argue with you about it

Answer (score 6):

> Second Maccabees seven one and twenty through thirty-one.

Or to be more explicit:

> Second Maccabees chapter seven, verses one and twenty through thirty-one.